# Can't Launch Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1.26 on Windows

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Recently, I tried to install the latest version of Android Studio (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1.26) on my computer. Initially, it went well. It asked me for my SDK version, and I installed android studio at my `D: Drive`, as my `C: Drive` was only left with 7 GB of space. So, I had to download an emulator. As the emulator takes up around 10 GB, I tried to install the emulator on my d drive by changing the path variable `ANDROID_HOME` to a folder in my `D: drive`. As I copied the contents from my `.Android` to my D Drive folder, that's when the problem began.

After I restarted my computer, I discovered that I could not open my android studio at all. I ran windows PowerShell on the folder and executed `studio.bat`, and it appears that the issue lies with the JDK version of 17.0. I changed my `JAVA_HOME`, `JDK_HOME`, `STUDIO_JDK` to JDK 11.0 and managed to launch android studio FRONT PAGE. Not the IDE, only the front image, and it jumped a lot of error of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

Here is my Log FIle:

```
2022-01-20 20:35:06,137 [   6331]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4  Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034 
2022-01-20 20:35:06,137 [   6331]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.10; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2022-01-20 20:35:06,137 [   6331]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10 
2022-01-20 20:35:06,137 [   6331]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:  
2022-01-20 20:35:06,138 [   6332]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.fus.FeatureUsageLogger 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.fus.FeatureUsageLogger
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.events.VarargEventId.log(EventId.kt:108)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.events.VarargEventId.log(EventId.kt:104)
    at com.intellij.featureStatistics.fusCollectors.LifecycleUsageTriggerCollector.onError(LifecycleUsageTriggerCollector.java:154)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.DefaultIdeaErrorLogger.canHandle(DefaultIdeaErrorLogger.java:63)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.DialogAppender.appendToLoggers(DialogAppender.java:86)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.DialogAppender.lambda$queueAppend$0(DialogAppender.java:59)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:976)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:843)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:773)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:453)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:828)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:507)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1063)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:874)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:670)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:641)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:335)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:270)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException.logAndExit(StartupAbortedException.java:86)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException.processException(StartupAbortedException.java:34)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.processException(IdeEventQueue.java:700)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I even changed my JDK version to android studio own JDK Version, and I still get this log file.

The steps that I have taken are:

1. Delete my SDK Installation Directory
2. Went to `\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3' and Deleted all the contents in my folder
3. Went to `\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3`and Deleted all the contents in my folder
4. Added `disable.android.first.run=true` to my idea.properties
5. Open Android Studio Offline
6. Deleted `.Android`, `.Gradle`, `.m2` from my Users Folder
7. Reinstall the Older version, Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1.22 but the problem persists
8. Did all the above steps in my C Drive, deleted everything first, did a fresh install, the problem persists

It is at this point, that I think that my only solution is to download android studio using a VM and run it on my computer. However, I would like to avoid using this solution, as you know, Android Studio requires a lot of processing power, and I think my computer is more likely to crash before I can even develop an application.

I need to use the android studio as it is compulsory for my school work in my university.

Note: I am unable to replicate the initial process of choosing where to download the SDK file for the android studio (After Deleting Everything stated in the above steps), if anyone could provide me advice on that, I would be extremely thankful.

TLDR: I was initially able to launch android studio, but after changing the directory for my emulator, I am now unable to open it. The log File is provided above. I have uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times, and I can't launch the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I found the problem instead. Turns out I didn't properly check for my file URL in my system path environment. The issue lies with `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`. I deleted the file directory, and there was a unknown symbol at the front of the file URL. I manually set the file url in CMD instead using the command `setx`.